# How do I get a Python cgi script running in Apache2

Tags: python, apache, server, apache2, cgi

I have a very simple `test.py` located at `/var/www/html/master.com/` that I'm trying to run in Apache2, on Ubuntu 18.1

My Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print("<h1>Hello</h1>")
```

What I have run so far:

Run `a2enmod cgi` to enable cgi:

```
ISimon@simon-EasyNote-TK85:~$ a2enmod cgi
Your MPM seems to be threaded. Selecting cgid instead of cgi.
Module cgid already enabled
```

Created the file `cgi-enabled.conf` at `/etc/apache2/conf-available/`, which contained the following:

```
# create new
# process .cgi and .py as CGI scripts

<Directory "/var/www/html/master.com">
  Options + ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
</Directory>
```

Restarted Apache2 with `systemctl restart apache2`

I then went to [`http://localhost/test.py`](http://localhost/test.py) and it offered to download the file.  It should display as plain html.

How do I get my server configured properly?

Comment: usually CGI scripts are executed only in folder `cgi-bin`. Maybe you should put code in subfolder `cgi-bin` and run http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py

Comment: maybe script have to be set as executable - `chmod a+x test.py`. And it should have `shebang` (`#!`) in first line to inform what program should run this code - ie, `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Comment: @furas  I has the shebang line, and I tried the command `chmod a+x test.py` sadly it did exactly the same

Comment: @furas doing as you suggested in the first comment returned an internal server error. I will try `chmod` now

Comment: please, always add code, data and error message in question, not in comment - they will be more readable and all people will see it.

Comment: @furas I'll edit it in.  Thank you.  `chmod` solved it.  Can you please leave an answer so that I can accept it.  also do you know how I can make it so that I can change the path.  I don't really want to navigate to `localhost/cgi-bin` when I could just go to `localhost`.  Thank you anyway. That was much easier than I expected

Comment: I checked apache doc and it shows your configuration as method to run it in main folder. Frankly, I don't use `CGI` but web frameworks like Flask, Django because it is easier to write code - they have many elements which helps. And code is better organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe have to set script as executable

```
chmod a+x test.py
```

And it should have shebang (`#!`) in first line to inform system what program should run this code - ie.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```